# Use MySQL as information destination

Tags: realm-mobile-platform

I have been testing Realm Mobile Platform and I had a question.

Is it possible that the data that you manage on the phone (with realm) instead of being inserted in the realm object server, is sent to a MySql database?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked in the realm forum and the answer was this:

> Yes, with the Enterprise Edition there are options to connect with external 
>   databases. I can recommend asking for a demo here: https://realm.io/pricing/